# Do we need adobe Digital Marketing Suite's authentication for appMeasurement for my ios app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, adobe-analytics

I just want to use adobe's omniture for my IOS app so do i need to make an account on Digital Marketing Suite in omniture.Can any one provide me any **sample source code** in which omniture has been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you or your organization are an existing Digital Marketing Suite customer (now known as the Adobe Experience Cloud), you can obtain all the measurement libraries by navigating to the Code Manager in Adobe Analytics. You can also obtain implementation code examples in their help interface here:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics/implementation/home.html

If you are not an existing user, there's not much reason or use to implement code because you wouldn't be able to access any reports that result from it.

Comment: My client want to use Adobe Mobile Cloud Omniture for App analytic. Neither I nor my client is existing user of Adobe. We are new to Adobe world. Can you tell me where can i get this product and start integrating in my app. Ultimately my client want to have reports of app usage.

Comment: You will want to contact Adobe's sales team. There is a link at the bottom of this page you can follow to get in contact with them: http://www.adobe.com/solutions/digital-marketing.html